# Is there anyway to optimise this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

It takes a long time to complete but would love to be able to pull the information that it gathers quickly.

```
SELECT *
FROM releases
WHERE (artist IN (SELECT artist FROM artist_love WHERE user='Quickinho')
OR
label IN (SELECT label FROM label_love WHERE user='Quickinho')
OR
id IN (SELECT release_id FROM charts_extended WHERE artist IN (SELECT dj FROM dj_love WHERE user='Quickinho'))
OR
id IN (SELECT artist FROM releases WHERE id IN (SELECT release_id FROM charts_extended WHERE user='Quickinho'))
OR
id IN (SELECT label FROM releases WHERE id IN (SELECT release_id FROM charts_extended WHERE user='Quickinho')))
AND
id NOT IN (SELECT release_id FROM charts_extended WHERE user='Quickinho')
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0,102
```

Comment: please add table CREATE to the question. and add what this query returns `EXPLAIN ...` (... is your query)

Comment: subquery is relatively slower than JOIN and not supported by older MySQL server versions. Consider using JOIN.

Comment: You are probably missing some indexes there. Could you post an `EXPLAIN`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Avoiding any subselects (although not tested so please excuse any typos)

```
SELECT *
FROM releases
LEFT OUTER JOIN artist_love ON releases.artist = artist_love.artist AND artist_love.user = 'Quickinho'
LEFT OUTER JOIN label_love ON releases.label = label_love.label AND label_love.user = 'Quickinho'
LEFT OUTER JOIN charts_extended ON releases.id = charts_extended.release_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dj_love ON charts_extended.artist = dj_love.dj AND dj_love.user = 'Quickinho'
LEFT OUTER JOIN releases releases1 ON releases.id = releases1.artist
LEFT OUTER JOIN charts_extended charts_extended1 ON charts_extended1.artist = releases1.id AND charts_extended1.user = 'Quickinho'
LEFT OUTER JOIN releases releases2 ON releases.id = releases2.label
LEFT OUTER JOIN charts_extended charts_extended2 ON charts_extended2.artist = releases2.id AND charts_extended2.user = 'Quickinho'
LEFT OUTER JOIN charts_extended charts_extended3 ON charts_extended3.release_id = releases.id AND charts_extended3.user = 'Quickinho'
WHERE (artist_love.user IS NOT NULL
OR label_love.user IS NOT NULL
OR dj_love.user IS NOT NULL
OR charts_extended1.user IS NOT NULL
OR charts_extended2.user IS NOT NULL)
AND charts_extended3.user IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that the optimized queries the others have offered aren't still fast enough.

Let's say your original query took 120 seconds to execute, and the best optimized query still takes 30 seconds, But you need a response time of 5 seconds or better. What can you do?

### Prepopulate!

Run the query triggered by a **cron job** executed regularly, for example **every hour**. Use an `INSERT SELECT` query like this:

```
INSERT INTO releases_queried
SELECT -- your query (your original one or one of the optimized ones)
```

See [MySQL Manual INSERT-SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html). Then you will get results from

```
SELECT * FROM releases_queried
```

immediately within **milliseconds**. It's a well known technique to improve response times. It works well if data needed for the query is always available.

### Real world usage

StackOverflow itself has many complicated queries not done on request, but asynchronously. Badges aren't calculated on each visit, but by cron.

Comment: Thanks Nalply, the query I'm running actually only takes around 3 seconds - maybe it is as optimised as it can be? The other solutions offered above seem to take far longer and often cause the releases table to lock.

Comment: And 3 seconds is too long for you? Then you need to pre-create the results like as of my proposal, if you can.

Answer (score 3):

```
...from releases
WHERE (artist IN (SELECT artist FROM artist_love WHERE user='Quickinho')
```

I would recommend you to use `JOIN` instead of doing `IN (SELECT..)`

You could do something like

```
select r.* from releases r, artist_love al 
where r.artist = al.artist and al.user='Quickinho'
```

Answer (score 2):

**IN() and NOT IN() subqueries are poorly optimized**

MySQL executes the subquery as a dependent subquery for each row in the outer query. This is a frequent cause of serious performance problems in MySQL 5.5 and older versions. The query probably should be rewritten as a JOIN or a LEFT OUTER JOIN, respectively.

**SELECT ***

Selecting all columns with the * wildcard will cause the query's meaning and behavior to change if the table's schema changes, and might cause the query to retrieve too much data.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly - make all fields used in JOIN relations indexed.

Then try this query -

```
SELECT
  r.*
FROM
  releases r
LEFT JOIN (SELECT artist FROM artist_love WHERE user='Quickinho') al
  ON al.artist = r.artist
LEFT JOIN (SELECT label FROM label_love WHERE user='Quickinho') ll
  ON ll.label = r.label
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT release_id FROM charts_extended ce
    INNER JOIN (SELECT dj FROM dj_love WHERE user='Quickinho') djl
      ON djl.dj = ce.artist
    ) ce
  ON r.id = ce.release_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT artist FROM releases r
    INNER JOIN (SELECT release_id FROM charts_extended WHERE user='Quickinho') ce
      ON r.id = release_id
  ) r2
  ON r2.artist = r.id OR r2.label = r.id

LEFT JOIN (SELECT release_id FROM charts_extended WHERE user='Quickinho') ce2
  ON ce2.release_id = r.id

WHERE
  (al.artist IS NOT NULL OR ll.label IS NOT NULL OR ce.release_id IS NOT NULL OR r2.id IS NOT NULL)
  AND ce2.release_id IS NULL
GROUP BY
  r.id
```

Comment: "JOIN (SELECT ...)" - I don't like that at all. I suggest moving the WHERE condition to WHERE where the "IS NOT NULL" checks are (so it can be "JOIN table ON ..."), or putting it as part of the "ON" part of the join (so "ON ... AND user='...').

Comment: I do not like subqueries either. So, filters can be moved to WHERE clause. About the 'ON...AND user', you shouldn't do it for LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Kickstart's solution is the right idea (though I suggest you JOIN on USER as well if possible, having "user = 'Quickinho'" appear so many times is not good practice), and then consider adding indices to some or all of the following fields:

- artist_love.artist
- label_love.label
- charts_extended.release_id
- dj_love.dj
- releases.artist
- releases.label
- charts_extended.release_id

Though I can't say I can think what you're trying to do with this. There is likely a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can search `key_cache`,`SQL` `Partition`,`performance tuning`;

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `JOIN` to increase the performance. In JOINs RDBMS can create an execution plan which is better for your query, unlike the sub-query where it will run all the queries and load all their data to do the processing.